# What is the fastest way to get NSAttributedString drawn into a CVPixelBufferRef

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsattributedstring, accelerate-framework, cvpixelbuffer

What is the most performant means for getting text via `NSAttributedString:drawAtPoint` into a RGBA32 `CVPixelBufferRef`?

Just to clarify my objective...

I'm being handed `CVPixelBufferRef` objects @60fps via a `CVDisplayLink` whilst a movie is playing.  These are getting wrapped in `CMSampleBuffers` for output.  I am using Apple's "AVGreenScreenPlayer" sample code as my base to work from.

I have an `NSAttributedString` object which represents a string (eg. @"ABC").  I want to draw this onto a small background (possibly) and then draw this resulting text w/background into the `CVPixelBufferRef`, into a corner of the video that is playing.

While the use of a `CIFilter` would likely be the most performant, I need access to a video frame containing the video+overlay result as a `CVPixelBuffer` or `vImageBuffer`.

For MacOSX 10.10.3. - Objective C.

Comment: Swift or Objective-C?

Comment: @st3fan This would be for Objective-C.  And I suspect I'll *need* to use vImageCopyBuffer (Accelerate framework) along the way.